# Getting "Error: Access Denied" when Target Audience to Sharepoint Groups for webpart

Tags: 2007, web-part, audience-targeting

I am trying to target a webpart to members of SharePoint groups.  I'm doing this through the `Advanced -> Target Audiences` option for the webpart, and no issues seem to arise when actually adding the groups here.

However, I am getting the full "Error: Access Denied" page when anyone other than a site administrator tries to access the page that the webpart is part of -- even if they are a member of the group I am targeting to.

So I kind of have two issues -- first off, why members of the right group aren't able to view the webpart.  Second, why is it a full access denied page -- shouldn't it just hide the individual webpart, not block the whole page?

Note: the webpart is simply a Content Editor Web Part.

Comment: I've noticed that this issue doesn't occur if I add the 'Read' permission level for the group to the section in which the webpart is contained.  Previously the group had 'Restricted Read' permission level.

Comment: Did you try to check with a farm user?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In our case we had created our own permission levels and there "Browse User Information  -  View information about users of the Web site." right was missing. Activating it solved the issue.